# How can I use bash to filter multiple patterns and one line before just only pattern?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with multiple lines:

```
line1
line2
line3
line_before
line4
line5
line6
```

and 3 patterns:

```
line2
line4
line6
```

Expect:

```
line2
line_before
line4
line6
```

I try use `grep -B 1` but it show line before any patterns.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow (SO). [SO is a question and answer page for professional and enthusiast programmers](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add your own code to your question. You are expected to show at least the amount of research you have put into solving this question yourself.

Comment: Thank you, @Cyrus. I edited my question. Please reopen it.

Comment: @mbrother I would say just reask the question as it probably won't get reopened or will take a while. Also though I would say your question still needs some more. You need to show what you've actually done and the output you are getting thus far

Comment: `How can I use bash to filter multiple patterns and one line before just only pattern?` You can read the file line by line and remember the previous line on each line and check if each line matches the pattern, if it does, then if the line matches also some other pattern, then print the previous line and current line, otherwise print only the current line. Repeat that process for each line. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

With awk...

In my exemple, your file with multiple lines is named "`file.txt`" and the file with 3 patterns is `filem.txt`.

The awk `filter.awk` program:

```
#! /bin/awk -f

NR == FNR && NR != 2 {
    # First file: Save 1st en 3rd tokens
    m[$0]=1
    next
}
NR == FNR && NR == 2 {
    # First file: Save 2nd token
    b[$0]=1
    next
}

NR != FNR {
    # Second file

    # Search line in tokens
    for (e in m) {
        if ($0 == e) {
            # Print current line
            print
            old = $0
            next
        }
    }
    for (e in b) {
        if ($0 == e) {
            # Print previous line
            if (FNR > 1) print prev
            # Print current line
            print
            old = $0
            next
        }
    }
}
{
    # Save current line
    prev = $0
}
```

Execute like this (files order is very important):

```sh
awk -f filter.awk filem.txt file.txt
```

Output:

```
line2
line_before
line4
line6
```

Answer (score 0):

**I am assuming you want** `-B1` **for only** `-e line4`.  (I would phrase that as:  "*How can I grep for multiple patterns, including the line before only one?*")

Suggestions with `grep -zPo`:

`grep -zPo '\v\K(line[26]|\V*\vline4)(?=\v)' file`

or (same regex, different syntax):

`grep -zPo '(?<=\v)(line[26]|\V*\vline4)(?=\v)' file`

Both output this:

```
line2
line_before
line4
line6
```

Explanation:

- `-z`: consume entire file
- `-P` support perl regexes
- `-o`: output only matching strings (one line at a time)
- `\v`: vertical whitespace character
- `\v\K` or `(?<=\v)` : Require vertical whitespace before match, but do not include it in match
- `(?=\v)`: require vertical whitespace after match, but do not include it in the match
- `\V*\vline4` : for the `line4` pattern, include the preceeding line (all not-vertical-whitespace-chars, a linebreak, and then the matching line -- to mimic `grep -B1 line4`